# Ошибка TypeError: string indices must be integers. Python

Tags: python-3.x, json, telegram, aiogram

Пишу бота, который собирает данные с Telegram профиля пользователя. Вот блок кода с которым возникли проблемы.

```
DATABASE_FILE = 'user_profiles.json'


def load_user_profiles():
    try:
        with open(DATABASE_FILE, 'r') as file:
            return json.load(file)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return []


def save_user_profiles(user_profiles):
    with open(DATABASE_FILE, 'w') as file:
        json.dump(user_profiles, file, indent=4)

@dp.message_handler(commands=['start'])
async def start(msg: types.Message):

    user_profiles = load_user_profiles()
    user_id = str(msg.from_user.id)
    
    profile = next((user for user in user_profiles if user['user_id'] == user_id), None)
    if profile:
        # Пользователь уже есть в базе данных, обновляем данные
        profile['username'] = msg.from_user.username
        profile['profile_link'] = f"https://telegram.me/{msg.from_user.username}"
        profile['phone_number'] = msg.from_user.phone_number or None
    else:
        # Новый пользователь, добавляем профиль в базу данных
        profile = {
            'user_id': user_id,
            'username': msg.from_user.username,
            'profile_link': f"https://telegram.me/{msg.from_user.username}",
            'phone_number': msg.from_user.phone_number or None
        }
        user_profiles.append(profile)
    
    save_user_profiles(user_profiles)
```

После команды `/start` терминал выдает ошибку `TypeError: string indices must be integers` ссылаясь на   `profile = next((user for user in user_profiles if user['user_id'] == user_id), None)`

Помогите в решении данной задачи.

Comment: Надо смотреть, что у вас лежит в user_profiles.json. Судя по ошибке, такое впечатление, что у вас там список строк вместо ожидаемого списка словарей.

Comment: Хм, и правда, в файле именно строки. Возможно, это корень проблемы?

Comment: Да, проблема в этом. Вам надо понять, откуда там берутся строки, если код заточен именно на сохранении в формате словарей. Возможно, изначально файл заполнялся каким-то другим скриптом или вручную?